# how to configure service worker in react project ( npx create-react-app)?

Tags: service-worker

I'm creating a pwa with reactJS but I can't get google lighthouse to recognize it as such. I created the project with npx create-react-app and these are the configuration files to get the service workers works:

**registerServiceWorker.js**

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  console.log("register", process.env.PUBLIC_URL)
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
console.log(swUrl)
      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        console.log("registerValidSW", swUrl)
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect, HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.jsx";
import RtlLayout from "layouts/RTL.jsx";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";
import { store } from "helpers/store.js";
import LoginPage from "views/Pages/LoginPage.jsx";
import "assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.5.0";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute";
import PDVDetails from "./views/Pages/PDVDetails";
import RegisterUserClientPage from "./views/Pages/RegisterUserClientPage";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
//import { App } from './App';
const hist = createBrowserHistory();

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        textAlign: 'center'
      }
    }
  }
});
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        {/* <Route path="/admin/PDVDetails/:id" component={PDVDetails} /> */}
        {/* <Route path="/auth/Login-Page" component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path="/auth/Register-user-client/:id" component={RegisterUserClientPage}/> */}
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
      </Switch>
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**service-worker.js**

```
/**
 * The workboxSW.precacheAndRoute() method efficiently caches and responds to
 * requests for URLs in the manifest.
 * See 
 */
// Precarga la app

importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.5.0/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
  console.log(`Yay! Workbox is loaded `);

  workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

} else {
  console.log(`Boo! Workbox didn't load `);
}
// self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || [])
// workbox.precaching.suppressWarnings()
// workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {})

// App Shell
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html')
console.log("service worker js")

// La API usa Stale While Revalidate para mayor velocidad
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https?:\/\/mi.app.com\/api\/.*/, 
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate(),
 'POST')

// // Last fuentes van con Cache First y vencen al mes
// workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https:\/\/fonts.(?:googleapis|gstatic).com\/(.*)/, 
//   workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
//     cacheName: 'google-fonts-cache',
//     plugins: [
//       new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
//         maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
//       })
//     ]
//   }),
//   'GET')


// Todo lo demás usa Network First
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/^https?.*/,
  workbox.strategies.networkFirst(), 'GET')
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "short_name": "ComercialPWA",
  "name": "Comercial VEGA PWA",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "related_applications": [],
  "prefer_related_applications": false
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
          manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
          homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
        -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="ComercialPWA" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

    <link
      rel="apple-touch-icon"
      sizes="76x76"
      href="%PUBLIC_URL%/apple-icon.png"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css"
    />
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jvectormap/2.0.4/jquery-jvectormap.css"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
    />
    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!--
          Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
          It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
          Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

          Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
          work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
          Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
        -->
    <title>Vive una experiencia única con Novaventa</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app. </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
          This HTML file is a template.
          If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

          You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
          The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

          To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
          To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
        -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "material-dashboard-pro-react",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.5",
    "@material-ui/icons": "3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "chartist": "0.10.1",
    "dashboard": "0.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.10.0",
    "history": "4.7.2",
    "immutability-helper": "^3.0.1",
    "material": "^0.4.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.27",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nouislider": "13.1.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "0.20.3",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "4.4.1",
    "react-chartist": "0.13.3",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dnd": "^7.0.2",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
    "react-jvectormap": "0.0.6",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-number-format": "^4.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.51",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.1",
    "react-table": "6.9.2",
    "react-tag-input": "^6.4.2",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "serve": "^9.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "serve ./build -s -p 5000",
    "copy": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/**/* src/**/* src/* build",
    "build": "npm run copy && workbox injectManifest workbox-config.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "npm run build",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx;  exit 0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext=js,jsx --fix;  exit 0",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss src/assets/css/material-dashboard-pro-react.css --source-map true"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.30.16",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "ajv": "6.9.1",
    "prettier": "1.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "copyfiles": "^1.2.0",
    "workbox-cli": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

these are screenshots from the google inspector:
[manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFXkD.png)
[service-worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vuujl.png)

the page has the ssl certificate configured too and this is the report generated by google lighthouse:
[Google lighthouse report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xk8u.png)

**What is missing to solve these problems?**